# Need to test controller HTTP methods with NUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I've written a back-end in C# with simple HTTP methods. Get, Post (create), Put (update), Delete.

Now I want to implement some unit tests with NUnit. I've found [this article](http://hippieitgeek.blogspot.ch/2013/02/a-beginner-tutorial-on-writing-unit.html) where the basics of NUnit are described. But now the question is, how do I use this to create the unit tests?

Can anybody explain what I have to do to test the controllers HTTP methods?

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT:**

To make things clear, I want to test if its possible to get, create, update, delete items over my controller class.

Comment: Without assuming things it is difficult to answer the question. Did you "install" Nunit framaework to the test project, what kind of code inside controllers? Without seeing the code it is impossible to say how and what you want to test.

Comment: What did you try and what's the problem? Are you trying to test the *wrong* thing perhaps? It's very *easy* to test controllers. You don't need to set up the entire ASP.NET stack. Just create an instance of the controller, pass any dependencies in the constructor and call the action methods with the actual parameters

Comment: *What* are you trying to test? The *Controller* isn't responsible for HTTP verb filtering or routing. The answer posted by Verendus shows how easy it is to test the methods

Comment: You can use [Isolator](https://www.typemock.com/docs?book=Isolator&page=Documentation%2FHtmlDocs%2Fmockingaspdotnetmvc.htm) if you need a powerful tool but it's pricey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using ASP.NET MVC, you can do something like this:

```
 public class ProductController : Controller
 {
      public ActionResult Index()
      {
           // Add action logic here
           throw new NotImplementedException();
      }

      public ActionResult Details(int Id)
      {

           return View("Details");
      }
 }


 [TestFixture]
 public class ProductControllerTest
 {
      [Test]
      public void TestDetailsView()
      {
           var controller = new ProductController();
           var result = controller.Details(2) as ViewResult;
           Assert.AreEqual("Details", result.ViewName);

      }
 }
```

Example taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/unit-testing/creating-unit-tests-for-asp-net-mvc-applications-cs

Comment: OP want's to use NUnit so it should be `[TestFixture]` and `[Test]` :)

Answer (score 1):

Personally I tend to avoid putting much logic in the controllers themselves, as they are not that simple to test (as you can now see).

Rather, add a service layer which does any required business logic and test THAT.  that way the logic can be re-used in non-MVC situations too.

this way, your controller action can be reduced to something like:

```
//Controller action
IHttpResult DoSomething(string input)
{
    var model = SomeService.DoThings(input);
    return View("~/views/DoSomethingView.cshtml", model);
}
```

Which is so light that you can probably manage to sleep at night without needing to unit test it really, but `SomeService` can be completely unit tested easily.

Comment: Unless you put some view related logic in the view

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but in fact of some requirements, I cant create a service layer.

Comment: On the contrary, testability is one of the major advantages of using controllers. Instead of setting up the entire ASP.NET stack you simply create a Controller instance and call its methods. A service layer is used to separate business logic from request handling. If you hardcode services inside the controller, or hard-code *database connections* inside the service, you can't test either. That's neither the Controller's nor the Service's fault

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - is that in response to me?  I wouldn't want to hard code a reference to a concrete class in a controller.  `SomeService` would be some sort of interface injected in probably via constructor injection.  My point is simply that the controller isn't (IMO) a place to put logic that needs much testing as getting the actual content out of the response isn't that trivial, so it's far easier to simply put the logic elsewhere.. which also makes it more re-usable.

Comment: @RaphaelMüller: All you need to create is a class to put the logic in and test that.  You could think of this as a 'layer' if you like, but it's just a class.  Ideally you would also abstract this behind an interface & use that in the controller via dependency injection.  I struggle to see what sort of requirements would be THAT restrictive?